# fullcalendar past month container styling

Tags: javascript, css, fullcalendar

I try to style fullcalendar past month container to fill with the background color, I style the date, head by CSS works fine, but just this one won't work. I use chrome inspect to see the HTML tag, and change style in CSS,  it won't show up, please help. 
Thanks!

// Here's the HTML tag //

```
<td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-mon fc-other-month fc-past" 
data-date="2017-10-30"></td>
```

// My CSS //

```
.fc-day .fc-widget-content .fc-other-month .fc-past {
background: orange !important;}
```

Thank you all.

Comment: We'll need more than that to know what's wrong. Do you have the CSS you're using? Is it possible that JS is modifying something? Could there be an element inside it that's overriding the background? Could there be another class on there that's overriding the background? Have you tried adding `!important` to see if it forces it to work? There's quite a lot you could do regarding troubleshooting, but it's hard to tell with so little information

Comment: Hi Matt Fletcher, thank you for your response, I did put !important on the CSS, but not working yet. Thank you.

Comment: Cheers for adding the CSS. The problem became quite clear when I saw it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. You are using this CSS:

```
.fc-day .fc-widget-content .fc-other-month .fc-past {}
```

... but that means `.fc-past` *inside* `.fc-other-month` *inside* `.fc-widget-content` *inside* `.fc-day`.

However because your html has all those classes on the one element, you need to have a selector that says "match *all* these":

```
.fc-day.fc-widget-content.fc-other-month.fc-past {}
```

But really, you could just select one of them. Over-specificity is never a good thing.

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much! That makes so much sense.  Really appreciated that! :))

Comment: No problem, cheers for providing the necessary bits :) If you're happy with my answer I'd appreciate an upvote and an accept, thanks!

Comment: I think you posted the wrong link there! I don't have any experience with fullcalendar so I don't know the answer to anything specific like that. Do they have their own classes?

Comment: Sorry about that. It's okay! I will figure out. Thank you so much!